# Knockoutjs: Order of the bindings evaluation when using click and checked bindings in the same time

Tags: javascript, binding, mvvm, knockout.js

I can't figure out how can I access a value which has been updated by `checked` binding in the method associated with a `click` binding?

It seems that `checked` binding evaluates AFTER `click` binding, since in `click` binding method/handler I can't access `computed` property value which depends on array synchronized with `checked` binding.

Template for a single check box:

```
<script id="singleFilterTemplate" type="text/html">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: id }, 
                                          click: $root.testMethod,
                                          checked: $parent.selectedFilterIds">
    </li>
</script>
```

I've following hierarchy of view models:

```
- TopLevelViewModel ($root in template above, defines computed aggregatedSelectedIds property)
---- GroupViewModel_0 ($parent in template above)
-------FilterViewModel_0_0 (Each FilterViewModel is associated with a check box)
-------FilterViewModel_0_N 
---- GroupViewModel_N
-------FilterViewModel_N_0 
-------FilterViewModel_N_N
```

- `checked: $parent.selectedFilterIds`:  each time check box has been checked/unchecked - appropriate item in the `TopLevelViewModel.selectedFilterIds` array is updated
- `click: $root.testMethod`: whilst click on a check box I'm trying to grab current state of the all check boxes, for this purposes I've introduced computed property `aggregatedSelectedIds` which works well and represent aggregated state for the all `GroupViewModel.selectedFilterIds` values, basically it aggregates metadata from the all `selectedFilterIds` properties into a single value and in `testMethod()` I'm just calling `alert(topLevelViewModel.aggregatedSelectedIds())` to ensure that this property represents a list of currently selected filters.

So each time `testMethod()` called by `click` binding - I see previous state of the filters (value, computed by the `aggregatedSelectedIds`). So is there any way to force/push/evaluate `checked` binding before `click` binding? I tried `event` binding but got the same results. Perhaps I'm doing this in wrong way and missed something obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subscribe to changes to selectedFilterIds by doing

```
this.selectedFilterIds  = ko.observable();
this.selectedFilterIds.subscribe(function (value) {
    //Code from your click method goes here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since checking a checkbox will trigger both the checked and click events essentially simultaneously, the browser just decides it will fire one of the handlers first, so a simple fix would be to just use a timeout in your click handler.

Something like `setTimeout(function() { stuff }, 1)` should work.

Putting that in your click handler would "jump" out of the handler, let the checked handler fire and execute, and after that it would return back to the code in your timeout callback (after waiting 1ms if your checked handler was fast enough to finish before that, which I doubt)

Even if the checked handler fires first in some other browser, this solution would still work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but as long as I have other more native options I would avoid any work arounds. I found explicit subscription using `subscribe()` pretty interesting solution since I have full control over what I do. BTW, do you think that execution order of the events  could be different in different browsers? Looks strange for me but I'm not expert in cross-browser development so who knows

Comment: I don't remember any specifics, but I wouldn't be surprised if something (say older version of IE ;) ) would shuffle the deck a bit with regards to the ordering of events

Comment: Interesting, I understand that this would be a generic solution. I'm not familar with timeouts in javascript, could you please slightly extend your example?

Comment: It's pretty straightforward. You just put code you want executed where I have `stuff`. The second parameter `1` is the number of millisecs you want it to wait. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: Tried this, it does a trick with bound collection so in my handler I can see updated state but check boxes are messed up since represents previous state (the last selected chec box remains unchecked until I do a next selection).

Answer (score 0):

Normally, methods are bound and executed in the order that you well.. bind them.. looks like you are binding click first. Not sure how knockoutjs handles this though from the data-bind attr?

for example

```
$(this).click(function () { alert(1);})
    .click(function() {alert(2);});

// alert(1) is first
```

I realize that is jquery, but event bindings in pure js do the same.

Really the best way to do this, would be with deferreds or promises, but I don't know how that works in knockoutjs :(

Comment: Changing the order of `click` and `chekced` bindings does a trick but messed up a state of check boxes, so I got updated state in bound to `click` method bucheck boxes still shows previous state